# How to add new category to Convolutional Neural Network

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I have a trained model with 10 classes and i need to add new class without loosing the weights of the pre-trained. I know that in order to do this issue, I should first of all load the pre-trained, remove/replace the FC , freeze lower layers of the pre-trained model and train the network. So theoritical is clear but practically which method i should call for loading the previous trained model because i have confused between just restore the last checkpoint **saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint)** or by importing meta graph by calling **tf.train.import_meta_graph** .

According to freeze all the weights, i don't know which methods are responsible for that ? Any idea or if there any other possible way to add new class.

Comment: Using `import_meta_graph` will recreate the original graph (you want to build a slightly different one). `restore` only takes the values from the checkpoint variables and assigns them to their places. You have to create the graph first (perhaps manually), before you can assign the values with restore. Neither of these "freeze" the layers. To do that, just specify what variables you want to train when you call your optimizer/training_op (i.e. don't call the layers you want to freeze). Or set the variables to untraininable when you manually create your new graph (which you will restore).

Comment: @golmschenk , thanks for your reply. So that mean after restore the checkpoint variables I should initialize a new variable and then assign the old Variables that i have restored to them by using this to assign the variable tf.Variable.assign(tf.get_variable('weights', trainable = False)).

Comment: The restore only fills your _already_ built graph with the variable _values_ in the checkpoint file. So you need to build your graph (setting as trainable what you want), then restore (which will assign the checkpoint values to the variables with matching names), and then you can start running the graph.

Comment: ok thank you very much, i will try to implement that.